# Implement authentication endpoint with JWT

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I wan to implement authentication endpoint for Angular Login page. I tried to implement this [example](https://medium.com/@xoor/jwt-authentication-service-44658409e12c).

But I have 2 questions which are not clear:
1. What is the endpoint to which I need to make a POST request with user and pass in order to get a token as response?
Looking at the tutorial diagram it should be /users/login but I don's see this endpoint implemented:
[image]

2. I need to use custom SQL in order to get the user from the DB. Do I need to make a custom handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is there under `/users/signin` in [User Controller](https://github.com/murraco/spring-boot-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/murraco/controller/UserController.java). The method name is still login. The path `/users` is mapped to the `controller` and the `/signin` is mapped to the `method`
2. **Yes**. You will have to provide some custom implementation

   1. In `loadByUsername` method inside `MyUserDetails` you can only pass `username` as parameter.
   2. If you instead want to use some more filters then implement a different service and implement a method in it that returns instance `UserDetails` subclass which is then used by the `JwtTokenProvider` `getAuthentication()` method
   3. Put that in place of `@Autowired MyUserDetails` in [JwtTokenProvider](https://github.com/murraco/spring-boot-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/murraco/security/JwtTokenProvider.java) class
   4. Implement a method there that returns `UserDetails` with all the needed data that is then used in `JwtTokenProvider -> getAuthentication() method`